# Couldn't connect to Docker daemon on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, daemon

I would like to run multi-container application using `docker-compose` on Mac OS X El Capitan (v10.11.2).

However, the command `$ docker-compose up` command complains that it can't connect to the Docker daemon.

> ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.

Only after executing `$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` I do have access to the `docker-compose` command.

Why is this and how can I overcome this extra step?

Comment: Did you run `docker-compose` from a Docker Quickstart Terminal (assuming you're using Docker Toolbox)? Or from a plain terminal? That extra step should be required only in the second case.

Comment: I run it from a plain terminal

Comment: Docker needs to setup a few environment variables before it can be properly used, that's why the `eval` command is always needed every time you restart the docker-machine.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### Update for Docker versions that come with `Docker.app`

The Docker experience on macOS has improved since this answer was posted:

- The only prerequisite is now for `Docker.app` to be running.  Note that starting it on demand takes a while, because the underlying Linux VM must be started.
- Any shell then has access to Docker functionality.

By default, `Docker.app` is launched at login time (you can change that via its preferences).
If you instead prefer **starting and stopping Docker *on demand*** from the *command line*, here are **`bash` scripts** that do that, **`docker-start` and `docker-stop`**; place them anywhere in your `$PATH`.

When `docker-start` launches `Docker.app`, it waits until Docker has finished starting up and is ready.

---

**`docker-start`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $1 in
  -h|--help)
    echo $'usage: docker-start\n\nStarts Docker (Docker.app) on macOS and waits until the Docker environment is initialized.'
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
(( $# )) && { echo "ARGUMENT ERROR: Unexpected argument(s) specified. Use -h for help." >&2; exit 2; }

[[ $(uname) == 'Darwin' ]] || { echo "This function only runs on macOS." >&2; exit 2; }

echo "-- Starting Docker.app, if necessary..."

open -g -a Docker.app || exit

# Wait for the server to start up, if applicable.  
i=0
while ! docker system info &>/dev/null; do
  (( i++ == 0 )) && printf %s '-- Waiting for Docker to finish starting up...' || printf '.'
  sleep 1
done
(( i )) && printf '\n'

echo "-- Docker is ready."
```

---

**`docker-stop`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $1 in
  -h|--help)
    echo $'usage: docker-stop\n\nStops Docker (Docker.app) on macOS.'    
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
(( $# )) && { echo "ARGUMENT ERROR: Unexpected argument(s) specified. Use -h for help." >&2; exit 2; }

[[ $(uname) == 'Darwin' ]] || { echo "This function only runs on macOS." >&2; exit 2; }

echo "-- Quitting Docker.app, if running..."

osascript - <<'EOF' || exit
tell application "Docker"
  if it is running then quit it
end tell
EOF

echo "-- Docker is stopped."
echo "Caveat: Restarting it too quickly can cause errors."
```

---

#### Original, obsolete answer:

[Kevan Ahlquist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35977975/45375) shows what commands to add to your Bash profile (`~/.bash_profile`) to automatically initialize Docker on opening an interactive shell.

<sup>Note that you can always initialize Docker in a *new* shell tab/window by opening application `/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app` (e.g., via Spotlight).

From an existing shell, you can invoke it as `open -a 'Docker Quickstart Terminal.app'` (which also opens a *new* shell tab).

What this answer offers is a convenient way to start Docker in the *current* shell.</sup>

Adding the Bash **shell functions** below - `docker-start` and `docker-stop` - improves on Kevan's approach in the following respects:

- You can run `docker-start` *on demand*, without the overhead of starting the VM on *opening* the shell (once the Docker VM is running, initialization is much faster, but still takes a noticeable amount of time).
  (Of course, you can still opt to invoke `docker-start` right from your profile.)
- `docker-stop` allows stopping Docker and cleaning up the environment variables on demand.
- The functions ensure that Docker's error messages are not suppressed, and they pass Docker error exit codes through.
- Additional status information is provided.
- You may pass a VM name as a parameter; default is `default`.

Example:

```
$ docker-start
-- Starting Docker VM 'default' (`docker-machine start default`; this will take a while)...
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.
-- Setting DOCKER_* environment variables (`eval "$(docker-machine env default)"`)...
DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/jdoe/.docker/machine/machines/default"
DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
-- Docker VM 'default' is running.


$ docker-stop
-- Stopping Docker VM 'default' (`docker-machine stop default`)...
Stopping "default"...
Machine "default" was stopped.
-- Unsetting DOCKER_* environment variables (DOCKER_CERT_PATH, DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY)...
-- Docker VM 'default' is stopped.
```

---

**Shell functions for on-demand starting and stopping of Docker** (place them in, e.g.,  `~/.bash_profile` for global availability in your interactive shells).

**Note**: The functions work in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, but in `ksh` you have to rename them so as not to include a '-' in the function names.

```sh
function docker-start {
  typeset vm=${1:-default} sts
  case $vm in
    -h|--help)
      echo $'usage: docker-start [<vm>]\n\nEnsures that the specified/default Docker VM is started\nand the environment is initialized.'
      return 0
      ;;
  esac
  sts=$(docker-machine status "$vm") || return
  [[ $sts == 'Running' ]] && echo "(Docker VM '$vm' is already running.)" || { 
    echo "-- Starting Docker VM '$vm' (\`docker-machine start "$vm"\`; this will take a while)..."; 
    docker-machine start "$vm" || return
  }
  echo "-- Setting DOCKER_* environment variables (\`eval \"\$(docker-machine env "$vm")\"\`)..."
  # Note: If the machine hasn't fully finished starting up yet from a
  #       previously launched-but-not-waited-for-completion `docker-machine status`,
  #       the following may output error messages; alas, without signaling failure
  #       via the exit code. Simply rerun this function to retry.
  eval "$(docker-machine env "$vm")" || return
  export | grep -o 'DOCKER_.*'
  echo "-- Docker VM '$vm' is running."
}

function docker-stop {
  typeset vm=${1:-default} sts envVarNames fndx
  case $vm in
    -h|--help)
      echo $'usage: docker-stop [<vm>]\n\nEnsures that the specified/default Docker VM is stopped\nand the environment is cleaned up.'
      return 0
      ;;
  esac
  sts=$(docker-machine status "$vm") || return
  [[ $sts == 'Running' ]] && { 
    echo "-- Stopping Docker VM '$vm' (\`docker-machine stop "$vm"\`)...";
    docker-machine stop "$vm" || return
  } || echo "(Docker VM '$vm' is not running.)"
  [[ -n $BASH_VERSION ]] && fndx=3 || fndx=1 # Bash prefixes defs. wit 'declare -x '
  envVarNames=( $(export | awk -v fndx="$fndx" '$fndx ~ /^DOCKER_/ { sub(/=.*/,"", $fndx); print $fndx }') )
  if [[ -n $envVarNames ]]; then
    echo "-- Unsetting DOCKER_* environment variables ($(echo "${envVarNames[@]}" | sed 's/ /, /g'))..."
    unset "${envVarNames[@]}"
  else
    echo "(No DOCKER_* environment variables to unset.)"
  fi
  echo "-- Docker VM '$vm' is stopped."
}
```

Comment: @BrianArmstrong: The feature _does_ come with Docker, but as separate application `/Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app`, which initializes Docker in a _new_ terminal window. I presume that the reason for this separate entry point is that running Docker on OSX requires starting a VirtualBox-based Linux VM (in addition to setting environment variables) - which is overhead you don't want to incur every time you open a shell. What this answer offers is a convenient way of starting Docker _on demand_ from an _existing_ shell.

Comment: @mklement0 Awesome! Do you keep those commands in a repository somewhere?

Comment: @ManeatingKoala: No, sorry. This answer is currently the only source.

Comment: I login to macbook pro through ssh, and running "open -g -a Docker.app" on command line does not work:
  `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Docker.app with error -54.`
If the command line has to be run on GUI environment, then the command line is not of much help...

Comment: @zerox: Are you saying that `open -g -a Docker.app` works for you when run _locally_, but fails via SSH? Generally, `open -a` also works via SSH (but obviously only launches the app visibly only on the target machine).

Answer (score 24):

I have the following in my `~/.bash_profile` so I don't have to run the env command every time:

```
docker-machine start default 2>/dev/null # Hide output if machine is already running
eval `docker-machine env default`
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Quickstart Terminal, I restarted the "default" machine solved my problem

```
docker-machine restart default
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Then I was able to start composing my container with docker-compose up -d --build

Answer (score 1):

I my case helped: stop + remove all docker containers (Docker version 1.13.0-rc4)

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

After this "docker-compose up" run without Error "ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to start Docker for Mac."

Perhaps in some cases this Error-message is only caused by another errors, i.e. memory space problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Homebrew tap, here: https://github.com/nejckorasa/mac-docker-go

It includes a script to start/restart Docker daemon.

```
Usage: dckr [options]

Options:
  -k  | --kill        Kill Docker daemon
  -s  | --start       Start Docker daemon
  -r  | --restart     Restart Docker daemon
  -ka | --killall     Kill all running Docker containers
  -h                  Display help

  Defaults to restart if no options are present
```